# iPhone: taking a photos programmatically in burst mode

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

In one of my project I have to use the iPhone Camera in "Burst Mode". How it could be done, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to do it. However, you can work still achieve what you want with a small hack.

Make sure AVCaptureDevice has its [`activeFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/activeFormat) property set to the best resolution. Then you need to process say 10 frames/second. You can access the frames with the delegate method: [`captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate/captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:)

And for the sound you can just run a shutter sound with every processed frame.

Comment: Ok, where I need to use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput class? I need to override AVCamCaptureManager but which will be further steps?